# Where and when is the instance of PathClassLoader created in android source code?

Tags: java, android, classloader, java.library.path, android-native-library

When I was studying android source code, I noticed that the general class loader in app is an instance of `PathClassLoader`, and there is two constructors in this class. One is like:

```
 public PathClassLoader(String dexPath, ClassLoader parent) {
     super(dexPath, null, null, parent);
 }
```

and the other is like:

```
  public PathClassLoader(String dexPath, String libraryPath,
          ClassLoader parent) {
      super(dexPath, null, libraryPath, parent);
  }
```

But I cannot find the call of the second constructor in the source code during the procedure of app launching. So where does the value of libraryPath param come from? As it is known that **libraryPath** refers to the list of directories containing native libraries, and is used for initializing the  value of `nativeLibraryDirectories`, which is a field of DexPathList object. So if there is no call of the second constructor with three params, how can the value of  `nativeLibraryDirectories` be initialized? Therefore how can an app find its native libraries?

**Actually, I am wondering who determines the value of nativeLibraryDirectories?**

Hope some one can guide me in this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> So where does the value of **libraryPath** param come from?

You can use Android Studio search to find it out. Perform *"Find in Path"*, specifying the *"Scope"* parameter to directory of Android sources. As a text to find paste following regex expression:

```
new PathClassLoader\(\w+, \w+, \w+\)\;
```

This matches a call of the constructor with three params. Also, do not forget to check *"Regular expression"* checkbox:

[image]

Then in the preview tab you'll be able to see the results:

[image]

With the same technique you can find out who is calling `PathClassLoaderFactory#createClassLoader()` function:

[image]

In `ZygoneInit.java` you'll be able to locate following piece of code:

```
    /**
     * Creates a PathClassLoader for the system server. It also creates
     * a shared namespace associated with the classloader to let it access
     * platform-private native libraries.
     */
    private static PathClassLoader createSystemServerClassLoader(String systemServerClasspath,
                                                                 int targetSdkVersion) {
      String librarySearchPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");

      return PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(systemServerClasspath,
                                                      librarySearchPath,
                                                      null /* libraryPermittedPath */,
                                                      ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),
                                                      targetSdkVersion,
                                                      true /* isNamespaceShared */);
    }
```

Now, back to your questions.

> So if there is no call of the second constructor with three params...

There is, `ZygoteInit#handleSystemServerProcess()` calls `createSystemServerClassLoader()`, which would eventually call 3 args constructor of `PathClassLoader`.

> Actually, I am wondering who determines the value of **nativeLibraryDirectories**?

As you can see from the code above, it defaults to system property `"java.library.path"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems quite appropriate. I grep'ed the code before starting bounty but maybe overlooked.