# How to find implementation/subclass of android framework class

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, android-source

I know there's [android's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java). But how to find an implementation or subclass of some specific interfaces or abstract classes, like `FragmentManager`? It's annoying and upset when you're digging into source code to find bugs or try to understand how things work but only arrive at interfaces and abstact classes.

Thanks for share.

**Update:** OK, I find there's a inner class in `FragmentManager` that inherits it. But what about others, like context, some services? Maybe google helps sometimes, but what if it can't?

**Self conclusion:** Official API reference lists public sub-classes. If private or package-private are expected, they are supposed to be in same package or class file.

Comment: You may use jgrep from AOSP, to grep in Java source code. Quite useful when you don't have AOSP code in an IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just perform a search in android sources using Android Studio search. Particularly in this case you are interested in classes that extend from `FragmentManager`, which means, that you are searching for *"... extends FragmentManager"* through the sources:

[image]

Check **"Directory"** radio button and **"Recursively"** checkbox, pointing out path to sdk in the box.

Then in preview window you'll get prompted with matches:

[image]

You can also see an example of more specific search using regex in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521198/1083957) answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.